# detectar valor (true o false) de un ChecBox de un DataGridView

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

el problema que tengo es el siguiente:

tengo un data GridView que en la ultima columna tiene un checkbox, y necesito detectar cuando la casilla esté activada o desactivada. Pues al activar, necesito sumar los valores de otra celda (de la misma fila).

He intentanto esto (incluso lo que está comentado en el código), pero nada:

```
private void dgvCostos_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell celdaCheck = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dgvCostos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Pagar"].Value;

        if (celdaCheck)
        {
            TotalPagar();
        }

        /*
        bool celdaCheckeada = (bool)dgvCostos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value;

        if (celdaCheckeada)
        {
            TotalPagar();
        }*/
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si probaste tu código, pero la linea siguiente tiene un error, que saltará en tiempo de ejecución.

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell celdaCheck = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dgvCostos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Pagar"].Value;
```

Estas asignando el valor de la celda a una variable de tipo DataGridViewCheckBoxCell, si el valor de la celda es de tipo bool, saltara el siguiente error.
"No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.Boolean' al tipo 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxCell'."
Lo correcto seria:

```
 bool celdaCheck = (bool)dgvCostos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Pagar"].Value;
```

Tal como lo tienes escrito en el bloque comentado.
Pero este código puede fallar pues el valor de la celda puede estar establecido a null y puede que el valor de la celda no esté actualizada, si es la que tiene el foco, te recomiendo probar lo siguiente.

```
private void dgvCostos_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //hacer referencia a la propiedad EditedFormattedValue.
      if(dgvCostos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Pagar"].EditedFormattedValue != null)
      {
         bool celdaCheckeada = (bool)dgvCostos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Pagar"].EditedFormattedValue;

          if (celdaCheckeada)
          {
            TotalPagar();
         }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Eduardo, gracias, tu Respuesta es la correcta. Te agradezco.

Comment: @EricDaniel Estamos en este sitio precisamente para colaborar. Gracias por aceptar como correcta y por puntear mi repuesta.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el valor FALSO predeterminado para un `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` es nulo y el valor VERDADERO predeterminado es el valor booleano Verdadero. Esto causa un problema porque los valores booleanos no son anulables. Puede resolver este problema de dos maneras:

```
var cbxCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dgvCostos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Pagar"];

if (cbxCell.Value != null && (bool)cbxCell.Value)
{
    //....
}
```

La otra forma de resolver esto es establecer la propiedad `TrueValue` de la columna en algún valor. Esto se puede hacer en tiempo de diseño como se muestra:
[image: Descripcion Imagen]
Entonces puedes escribir:

```
if ((string)cbxCell.Value == "T")
{
    //...
}
```

Esto funciona porque las cadenas son anulables.

**Tenga en cuenta:** Aunque configuré `FalseValue` como F, el valor falso todavía parece ser nulo, por lo que sugiero ignorar la propiedad `FalseValue`.

---

**Otra nota:** SI coloca algo en `TrueValue` como se indicó anteriormente y luego intenta borrarlo, el valor `True` se vuelve nulo, lo que requiere que elimine la columna y luego la vuelva a agregar para restaurarla a la condición predeterminada. O puede cambiarlo en el código de la siguiente manera:

```
((DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn)dgvCostos.Columns["Selected"]).TrueValue = true
```

Answer (score 1):

básicamente lo que a mi me funciono fue agarrar el valor de la fila seleccionada

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)

        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].FormattedValue.ToString() == "True" ? false : true;
            MessageBox.Show(""+dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value);

        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez que tengas el valor puedes hacer el if que gustas.

Cabe mencionar que el valor no ocupas asignarlo, bastaría con esto.

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].FormattedValue.ToString()
```